# Establishing referential integrity in a generic table?

Tags: database-design

**Current Schema:**

```
 - DropDown:
     DropDownID PK, 
     Name nvarchar(25)

 - DropDownOption: 
     DropDownOptionID PK, 
     DropDownID FK, 
     Name nvarchar(25), 
     Description nvarchar(155)

 - Estimate: 
     EstimateID PK, 
     JobDifficultyID FK(DropDownOption), 
     JobTypeID FK(DropDownOption), 
     etc.

 - Note there are 5+ Tables With links to DropDownOption similar to Estimate.
```

How can I establish referential intregity (i.e. `JobDifficultyID` can only point to `DropDownOptions` that are apart of `JobDifficulty DropDown`) without creating separate tables (i.e. Instead of `DropDown` & `DropDownOption` having `JobDifficultyTypes`, `JobTypeTypes`, etc)

**Alternative Schema:**

```
- JobDifficultyType: 
    JobDifficultyTypeID PK, 
    Name nvarchar(25)

- JobTypeType: 
    JobTypeTypeID PK, 
    Name nvarchar(25)

- Estimate: 
    EstimateID PK, 
    JobDifficultyTypeID FK, 
    JobTypeTypeID FK, 
    etc.
```

This would result in at least 13 new tables. Is this the appropriate way or is there a robust way to combine all the miscellaneous types into a single table while maintaining referential integrity?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this design, which requires one more table:

```
 - DropDown:
     DropDownID  PK, 
     Name nvarchar(25)

 - DropDownOption: 
     DropDownID  FK (DropDown)  UQ1, 
     DropDownOptionID  PK       UQ1,
     Name nvarchar(25), 
     Description nvarchar(155)

 - Estimate: 
     EstimateID  PK, 
     etc.

 - EstimateOption: 
     EstimateID  PK,   FK1 (Estimate)
     DropDownID  PK    FK2 (DropDownOption), 
     DropDownOptionID  FK2 (DropDownOption)
```

For every row in `Estimate`, you'll have to add (up to) 13 rows in the `EstimateOption` table (one for each dropdown menu).

The additional `Unique` constraint in the `DropDownOption` table is needed for the `foreign key` (`FK2`) from the `EstimateOption` table.

What you have in your current design as `Estimate`, can then be constructed with a pivot query from the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,

It would be more than one table added, I guess I failed to elude to that. The Estimate table isn't the only table linking to DropDownOptions (my bad on not mentioning that).

It is nice to see an alternative I didn't see before even if it doesn't quite work. I decided to set a default to the JobDiffcultyID and JobTypeID properties respective options and use that to retrieve a list of options available as a temporary fix. Though this is a solution that'd I'd like to keep temporary.

Comment: The design could be adjusted for use with multiple tables (not trivial, you probably need a supertype/subtype pattern, if I understand correctly.)